# Fish that is "filled with fat"?

Tags: translation

I lived in Japan in the 90s and remember the (big) fish section in the supermarket. A label on one said, if I recall correctly,  "abura no tappiri" which I believe means 'filled with fat.'  Is that correct?  And is that considered a bragging point for fish?  (note: I never saw that on pork or beef)

Comment: Note:  [脂]{abura} means "fat"; [油]{abura} means "oil".  Probably referring to the health-beneficial oils that many fish contain.

Comment: There is no such word as *tappiri*. Is it a typo for *tappuri*?

Comment: FYI [脂](https://okjiten.jp/kanji286.html#a) consists of 'cut meat' and 'spoon in mouth'. The right hand side is a standalone character 旨 meaning tasty.

Comment: Try watching the YouTube channel きまぐれクック (or any Japanese cooking channel, there are many but this one is my favourite) and you will get the idea very quickly. If you are interested in this stuff, he's a good channel to watch for a beginner I'd say. He always explains what he does as he does it and describes different parts of the fish. You'll learn a bunch of new vocabulary withouth having to look it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

脂【あぶら】たっぷり (I believe *tappiri* is a typo for [*tappuri*](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%B7%E3%82%8A)) is a phrase meaning "fatty", "has put on a lot of fat" (but "filled with fat" is probably an overstatement). It's regarded as a good property of tasty fish. Fat-rich parts of tuna even have a distinct name ([トロ](https://matcha-jp.com/en/2646)). For beef, 霜【しも】降【ふ】り ("marbled", "fat-laced") is more common as a marketing phrase.

Note that 脂【あぶら】**の**たっぷり makes no sense in isolation. Perhaps you remembered it incorrectly or you remembered only a part of a longer phrase.